# How to always display center of background image?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I am using this `class` to get an image om my [webpage here](https://torza.nl/test_environment/vert/)

```
<section class="py-5 bg-image-full" style="background-image: url('img/huisman.jpg');">
```

But it seems that bootstrap is starting placing the image with the top left corner, no the best part of the image is not shown on smaller screens.

How can I make sure that the center of the image is always shown?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is two things:

Add `background-position: center;` to position the image in the center, and to cover as much as possible from the actual image in the actual space, you can use `background-size: cover;`.

In CSS:

```css
.py-5 {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Top and left is the default **background position**.

You can override this via:

```
background-position: center center;
```